# Email subscription form in octobercms

Tags: laravel, content-management-system, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am using [Email Subscription Form plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/jorgeandrade-subscribe). When I enter the email address in the form and click the submit button, the submitted email appears in the url and it redirects to the same page. I did the configuration as mentioned in the documentation but it is not working. Neither the subscription list is updated nor it shows the userProfile page.

```
<form name="form-subscribe-andradedev" id="form-subscribe-andradedev" data-request="formSubscribe::onAddSubscriber" data-request-update="'formSubscribe::alert': '#result'">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="* Email" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude">
        <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude">
    </form>
```

Comment: Reads like you need {% frameworks extras %} loading in the template somewhere. You also need the jquery loaded before that.

Comment: Yes you were right, now again I am having another issue. The subscriber list is updated in the backend but no email is sent neither does the profile form opens. I have added the code of the form can you please check it.

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to the mail configuration setting?

Comment: Would you create a new question on stack overflow with those those things while I look into this. I will put my answer down below as the answer so people looking into this problem know what the answer is.

Comment: I have solved it there was a problem with the configuration. Thank you for your help. I am getting a new problem can you please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reads like you need {% frameworks extras %} loading in the template somewhere. You also need the jquery loaded before that.